# Likelihood ratio test when multicollinearity is present

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio

I want to compare two nested regression models using a [likelihood ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) to examine whether there is a statistically significant difference between the two models. However, there is [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity#Remedies_for_multicollinearity) as the predictors are strongly correlated with each other. This is particularly the case for the larger of the two models. The small model has ~8 variables, whereas the larger model has ~14 variables. Are there any assumptions used for calculating the p-value of the likelihood ratio (LR) test that are violated when the predictors are strongly correlated?

Comment: You'll need to explain what likelihood ratio test & what variables you're talking about.

Comment: See the updated question.

Comment: Are these nested regression models & are the predictors the correlated variables you refer to? (The LRT example in your Wikipedia link is for association in a contigency table, & only two variables are  mentioned; so clearly correlation between them isn't a violation of assumptions - it's what's being tested for.)

Comment: Thanks. Do have a look to see if this isn't dealt with already on our site somewhere - the short answer is "no".

Comment: Ok, thanks! Hmm.. I've always try to look around (the related questions when writing a question are often quite good), but I didn't find anything in this case. Or perhaps I gave up too quickly due to the large amount of low quality questions on LR tests.